# Java 8 installed but I get [javac: invalid target release: 1.8.0_111] when compiling with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I installed Java 8 as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts

I have a project that I build with Ant. When I compile it against Java 8 I get this error:

```
[javac] Compiling 542 source files to /usr/share/feedxl-deploy/temp/FeedXLWebapp/HibernateUpdate/build/classes
[javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.8.0_111
[javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[javac] use -help for a list of possible options
```

In my build.xml I specified to use java 8 like this:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" source="1.8" target="1.8" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" encoding="utf8">
```

I have java, javac, and $JAVA_HOME set up as follows:

```
root@dev:~# java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
root@dev:~# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_111
root@dev:~# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
root@dev:~# env | grep -i java
DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

The command

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

lists both and I made sure Java 8 is set as system wide default.

I also made sure that the `java-current` link points to Java 8

```
root@dev:/usr/lib/jvm# ls -alh ./java-current
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec 12 06:52 ./java-current -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: How do you run it? from cli? Is it the same user? also, `which javac`

Comment: Aside from @exenza's questions, a side note: `PATH` shouldn't include Java directories, since `/usr/bin` is already in the path, and the Java-related links in `/usr/bin` will point to the proper executables. Use `update-java-alternatives` to set up the links in `/usr/bin` properly rather than adding things to `PATH`.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't set the target release to "1.8.0_111" somewhere in the build.xml file?  I say that because the release *should* be `1.8` and not `1.8.0_...`.

Comment: @exenza `javac 1.8.0_111` as you can see in the console output above. I run it from CLI, by issuing an `ant -F build.xml` command.
@ChaiT.Rex I didn't edit PATH by hand. All you see there was set up by `update-java-alternatives` or by `apt-get install`
@StephenC Yes, I am sure. `build.xml` contains only `1.8`

Answer (score 0):

How did your run it?

Try compile it manually something like this:

javac -version #check version
javac src/main/java/QuickSort.java -verbose
java -cp build/classes/main/ QuickSort